# Can the mysql_error() function be disabled in php?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I came across in a project of about **900** files with **3 millions lines of code**, and my boss asked me to find a solution to prevent mysql_error() to show errors.

This is the syntax
`mysql_query() OR die(mysql_error())`

So, how can I disable the **`mysql_error()`** from showing errors?

Comment: if a line of code can launch an error you can try to put @ before the function to suppress it if i recall correctly

Comment: What does that mean? `mysql_error` itself is not "showing errors". Does that mean you have a ton of `echo mysql_error()` everywhere throughout your code and you want to silence that?

Comment: `mysql_error` doesn't *show* errors. It returns a string. `echo`ing or `print`ing that error will display it. You need to fix the root cause (which is, frankly going to be a hell of a lot of work with that much code to dig through) — you will regret any shortcuts you take there. While you are at it, you should stop using the `mysql_` extension (which is deprecated and will be removed from PHP in the future) and upgrade to PDO or the `mysqli_` extension.

Comment: example change `echo mysql_error();` to `mysql_error()` or remove it. Voila it works.

Comment: Sorry, in the projects there are lots of `mysql_query() OR die(mysql_erro())`, I accidentally removed it editing the question

Comment: remove die(); you should really do it because I guarantee you that the logic of application will fail. Better fix problems and what's even more useful change engine to PDO or mysql because mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed.

Comment: Your bigger problem is that your error handling strategy is somewhere between horrible and non-existent. Silencing `mysql_error` is a drop in the bucket.

Comment: @Carl - I don't know why you voted on my answers so repeatedly but you have caused me some problems with moderators, please read [the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) and don't do it again, I just want to give my answers, not being targeted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still having errors then your project is not finished yet.

One way would be to do a site-wide find/replace on your files and replace the `OR die(mysql_error())` with an **@** in front of `mysql_error()` like so: `OR die(@mysql_error())`.

Placing an **@** in front of a function call suppresses error messages. But use it carefully, this is not always a good solution.

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872340/should-i-use-in-my-php-code/4872354#4872354) which links to [this article](http://anvilstudios.co.za/blog/php/how-to-ignore-errors-in-a-custom-php-error-handler/) to know if it's a good solution for you.

I would change all `OR die()` occourrences to a custom error-handling function, then if you get an error you will still know about it without displaying them to users.

Yes, it would take a lot of time, but a **good project takes a lot of time**.

Check [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/error-handling-in-php/) to create your own error-handling function and [this other one](https://perishablepress.com/how-to-enable-php-error-logging-via-htaccess/) to Enable `PHP` error logging via `.htaccess`, they really helped me.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look to the articles and they seem interesting and useful, I'm reading them.

Comment: You are welcome, but read DocRattie's answer too, it can be of help for you ;)

Comment: I read the articles, they are very interesting and useful, as soon as I reach 15 reputation I'll upvote your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
function mysql_own_error($debug = false){
   $msg = mysql_error();
   if($debug){
     echo $msg;
   }else{
     // Function to log errors here.
   }
}
```

With that you can set a global debug-variable `$debug`. Only if that is true output the error msg.
Now replace every `mysql_error()` with `mysql_own_error($debug)`. There are Editors that can do suche replaces fast.

With that you will prevent the `mysql_error()` from showing errors publicly but you can still debug the code if you need to.

Comment: Thank you Mr for your answer, but I should include a file containing the variable in all files because in the project there is no file which is included in ALL the other files

Comment: @Carl - as I said in my answer, if you want to make a good project, then you must work for a lot of time.

Comment: @Carl If you have no central config-file you should defenetly include one. With 3mio lines of code it will hardly be possible to manage errors without a config-file. And beside that it will help you overwall when you face other problems.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I read @CliffBurton's linked articles and now I think that *keeping logging errors without showing them to the user* is a better solution. But your answer was helpful too, as soon as I reach 15rep i'll upvote your answer

Comment: @Carl you could use the else-part as the place where to log errors. I edit it to show that. just as an idea on how to start with that. :)

Comment: Oh, thats right! So I'll use your function with the logging-error articles, Thank you all! *-*